Emulator shown as black in Appium Inspector
I’m using Appium Inspector 2024.3.4 to test the Spotify application. However, when I start the session, the app is running but only shows a black screen.
While searching for solutions, I came across this forum topic:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/emulator-shown-as-black-in-appium-inspector/2258
It was suggested to “Try disabling ‘Use Host CPU’ in your emulator settings.” However, I couldn’t find this setting.
Please help me resolve this issue!
screenshot
